# com.sun.xml.ws.transport.local.InVmServer: sample code and experiences?

Tags: jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I would like to run some junit test of some of our webservices.  Not just invoking the Java code, but going through `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint` of JAX-WS stack to ensure that things are working correctly.  We use the default implementation in Java 7 for testing - Metro 2.2.4 according to wsimport - and the default implementation in Java 6 for production.

However, the typical http binding needs a TCP/IP port to bind to, and I was wondering if it was possible to avoid the TCP/IP layer while keeping the rest of the JAX-WS stack.

It appears that com.sun.xml.ws.transport.local.InVmServer supports the "in-vm" transport which does exactly this, but I have a bit of trouble understanding the rather terse documentation and how to get it up and going from within a junit 4 test invoked by maven.

So, my question is:  How do I - in a junit setting invoked by maven - fire up the endpoint with the "in-vm" transport (probably using an executor), and invoke it from a client, and then shut the endpoint down.  Also, what are your experiences with this?